# Asp.net WebApi in 3rd party Web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have build a custom WebApi app using MVC which I have successfully deployed to a 3rd party standard Asp.net Web application (No Mvc). I can call my Api fine but it requires authentication to do so. The web.config is setup to allow Anonymous access to anything under the \Anonymous folder. Pretty standard.

Since you access the WebApi Controllers/Actions via a route rather than a physical path, how do I enable my WebApi Actions to be accessed Anonymously?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: Look at the [`AllowAnonymous`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.profilepropertysettings.allowanonymous(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.

Comment: I did a quick search on this and how to use this under for my situation wasn't obvious. Thanks for the reference though!

Comment: open the project properties and select allowanonymous to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Pretty simple. This worked:

```
<location path="api">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```